# html decoding and encoding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, radwindow

i am having an issue with html text in my application. the scenario is that, i can save text enetered into an editor(radeditor in my case), into an xml attribute. while saving i do like,

```
    Server.HtmlEncode(EditorGuidance.Content.Trim)
```

in some other part of my code, i need to create an image from code behind with an onclick javascript event attached to it, passing the value saved for this guidance field to the js method.

i do it like,

```
    Dim desc As String = control.Descendants("controlGuidance").First().Attribute("description").Value
    lblGuidanceImage.Text = "<img onCliCk=""DisplayControlHelp('" & HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(desc.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("'", "\'")) & "')"" style=""vertical-align:middle; padding-right:2px; cursor: pointer;"" src=""../Images/help.gif"" alt=""Click for additional guidance"" title=""Click for additional guidance"" />&nbsp;"
```

now, the js method i wrote have to get the radwindow in that page and display the passed text in that window.

```
    function DisplayControlHelp(helpText) {
    var wnd = $find("<%=RdWndGuidance.ClientID %>");
    var controlGuidance = document.getElementById("<%= lblControlGuidance.ClientID %>");
    helpText = $("<div/>").text(helpText).html();
    controlGuidance.innerHTML = helpText;
    wnd.show();
    }
```

now, this works for text having no html tags in it.

but this fails(image is rendered to the page, but click event not working) for text like

```
    &lt;p style=&quot;list-style-type: none; font-size: 15px;  font-family: Georgia, Century, Times, serif;   color: #333333; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 15px;  line-height: 21px; padding-right: 0px;border: 0px;&quot;&gt;Around 3,000 patients died needlessly last year as a result of poor care, and nearly half a million were harmed unnecessarily in the NHS,&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/news/jeremy-hunt&quot; style=&quot;list-style-type: none;    color: #058b7b; outline-width: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; outline-style: none; padding-left: 0px; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px;  outline-color: invert; padding-right: 0px;border: 0px;&quot; target=&quot;_hplink&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;Jeremy Hunt&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;will say today, as he calls on the health service to tackle the &quot;silent scandal of errors&quot;.&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p style=&quot;list-style-type: none; font-size: 15px;  font-family: Georgia, Century, Times, serif;   color: #333333; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 15px;  line-height: 21px; padding-right: 0px;border: 0px;&quot;&gt;The health service also recorded 326 &quot;never events&quot; - incidents so unacceptable that they should never happen in the last 12 months.&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p style=&quot;list-style-type: none; font-size: 15px;  font-family: Georgia, Century, Times, serif;   color: #333333; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 15px;  line-height: 21px; padding-right: 0px;border: 0px;&quot;&gt;The figures come amid revelations that the Care Quality Commission&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2013/06/21/cqc-cover-up-jill-finney_n_3476518.html?utm_hp_ref=uk&quot; style=&quot;list-style-type: none;    color: #058b7b; outline-width: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; outline-style: none; padding-left: 0px; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px;  outline-color: invert; padding-right: 0px;border: 0px;&quot; target=&quot;_hplink&quot;&gt;covered up a spate of mother and baby deaths&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;at Morecambe Bay Trust, and days after it was&amp;nbsp;shown the NHS had paid up to&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2013/06/12/nhs-gagging-orders_n_3426090.html&quot; style=&quot;list-style-type: none;    color: #058b7b; outline-width: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; outline-style: none; padding-left: 0px; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px;  outline-color: invert; padding-right: 0px;border: 0px;&quot; target=&quot;_hplink&quot;&gt;&amp;pound;2million to stop potential NHS whistleblowers&lt;/a&gt;from speaking out.&lt;/p&gt;
```

this is the htmlencoded text saved in the xml

can anyone let me know what am doing wrong, or what i need to do solve this. i tried many ways, but no luck yet.

any help is appreciated.